# What is the default Inheritance strategy in hibernate for a bean mapped to a database table?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

This is my first query in stackoverflow and I think I am providing all my necessary inputs:

I have provided my Java bean and the database table details below:

******Java Bean Class:***

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Column;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

import javax.persistence.Id;

import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity

@Table(name = "BANK_MESSAGES")

public class messagesBean implements Serializable

{

    @Id
    @Column(name="msg_id")
    private String msg_id;

    @Column(name="msg_date")
    Timestamp msgDateTime;

    @Column(name="message")
    private byte[] message;

    @Column(name="msg_type")
    private String msg_type;

    //Getters and Setters for the above fields
}
```

Below is the DDL for my Database Table (Oracle):

```
create table BANK_MESSAGES
(msg_id varchar2(10),
msg_date timestamp,
message blob,
msg_type varchar2(5)) ;
```

I am trying to understand what is the default Inheritance strategy in hibernate for a bean mapped to a database table like above ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you just have one entity without any subclass, inheritance is irrelevant.

Otherwise, [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Inheritance.html) has the answer:

> Annotation Type `Inheritance`
>
> ```
> @Target(value=TYPE)
> @Retention(value=RUNTIME)
> public @interface Inheritance
> ```
>
> Defines the inheritance strategy to be used for an entity class hierarchy. It is specified on the entity class that is the root of the entity class hierarchy. **If the Inheritance annotation is not specified or if no inheritance type is specified for an entity class hierarchy, the SINGLE_TABLE mapping strategy is used**.

(emphasis mine).

Comment: Thanks for the first line in your comments and I am clear now that there is no need for any inheritance as the mapping between the entity class and table are one to one.