# Why is hibernate searching for the discriminator column when it already knows the target type?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a couple of classes (Foo and Moo) that I'm working on in a hibernate application. Both classes extend Bar.

```
Foo --- extends ---> Bar 
Moo --- extends ---> Bar
```

Foo and Moo and Bar are identical in every respect apart from Foo and Moo each implement a different marker interface.

In otherwords, Foo implements IFoo and extends Bar. Moo implements IMoo and extends Bar. However neither IFoo or IMoo interface introduce any new methods to the picture as they're just marker interfaces.

In addition I have a couple of JPA repository classes.

```
@Repository
public class FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {
    public Foo findFooById(id);
}
```

and

```
@Repository
public class MooRepository extends JpaRepository<Moo, Long> {
    public Moo findMooById(id);
}
```

**Problem:**

When I call findMooById, I get an error:

> org.database.util.DatabaseException: ERROR: column bla.dtype does not
>   exist.

I'm aware that this is because hibernate is searching for a discriminator column.

**The Question**

My question is, why is hibernate searching for a discriminator column?

The return type of each repository already specifies a Moo or Foo return type. The Moo repository couldn't return a Foo if it wanted to!

A discriminator shouldn't be required to make the determination, right?

Comment: The query projection that you use in your `@Query` should match the properties of the Bar entity. Problem is probably related to the mismatch of your projection and entity members. Can you provide your `@Query` as well?

Comment: Apologies - I've updated the question to better reflect the situation. Are you saying that the query projection should only query using properties of the Bar superclass? 

My query is "select moo from Moo moo where moo.property = :property"

Comment: Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31746793/9601809). Obviously, when you do not specify an inheritance strategy, SINGLE_TABLE strategy is applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SINGLE_TABLE strategy (or simply using `@Inheritance` without specifying a strategy, i.e. falling back to default -simple table-), the discriminator column is ***REQUIRED*** as per JPA specification section 2.12 available at [this link](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1572814493_a24c813ca7da20100238e2d8e05c4f2a).

While it is possible to load an entity in some JPA implementations without specifying a discriminator column, doing so will not guarantee portability across JPA implementations.

Comment: I'm not using @Inheritance annotation at all.

Comment: how are you specifying inheretence strategy then?, can u plz post the Foo, Moo and Bar classes code, and the mapping file if any